# How can i Solve my Error in android studio 1.5?

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-3.0

frustrated by solving this issue help me.

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
Warning:Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
         In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages
Warning:Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
         In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages
Warning:Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5 is ignored for release as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
         In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages
Warning:Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5 is ignored for release as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
         In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareAndroidmadsLibraryQrgenearatorQRGenearator103Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2520Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72520Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2421Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportMediarouterV72520Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportMultidex101Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportPaletteV72520Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72421Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCompat2520Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUi2520Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUtils2520Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportFragment2520Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportMediaCompat2520Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42520Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2520Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServices1104Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAds1104Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAdsLite1104Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAnalytics1104Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAnalyticsImpl1104Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppinvite1104Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAuth1104Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAuthApiPhone1104Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAuthBase1104Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAwareness1104Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase1104Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement1104Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesCast1104Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesCastFramework1104Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesClearcut1104Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesDrive1104Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesFitness1104Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGames1104Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGass1104Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGcm1104Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesIdentity1104Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesIid1104Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesInstantapps1104Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesLocation1104Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMaps1104Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesNearby1104Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPanorama1104Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPlaces1104Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPlus1104Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesSafetynet1104Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesTagmanager1104Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesTagmanagerApi1104Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesTagmanagerV4Impl1104Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesTasks1104Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesVision1104Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesVisionCommon1104Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWallet1104Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWearable1104Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAnalytics1104Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAnalyticsImpl1104Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAppindexing1104Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAuth1104Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseCommon1104Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseConfig1104Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseCrash1104Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseDatabase1104Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseDatabaseConnection1104Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseDynamicLinks1104Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseIid1104Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseMessaging1104Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseStorage1104Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseStorageCommon1104Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:preparePlDroidsonroidsGifAndroidGifDrawable128Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:collectDebugMultiDexComponents UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug
Uncaught translation error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
Uncaught translation error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
Uncaught translation error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
Uncaught translation error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
Uncaught translation error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
Uncaught translation error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
Uncaught translation error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
Uncaught translation error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
Error:java.lang.InterruptedException: Too many errors
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:607)
    ... 4 more
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 6 mins 22.957 secs
Information:2 errors
Information:4 warnings
Information:See complete output in console

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.something.home.bloodbank"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 2
        versionName "2.0"

        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }   


    android {
        useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'



    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'

    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.8'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.4'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5'

    compile 'androidmads.library.qrgenearator:QRGenearator:1.0.3'
}


android {
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

More information would be helpful,
Try changing you gradle (build.gradle) to this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.something.home.bloodbank"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    android {
        useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'


    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'



    implementation 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'

    implementation 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    implementation 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.8'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.4'
    implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5'
    implementation 'androidmads.library.qrgenearator:QRGenearator:1.0.3'
}




android {
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'

    }
}
```

Comment: Error:(28, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'implementation()'
Possible causes:<ul><li>The project 'BloodBank' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
<a href="open.wrapper.file">Open Gradle wrapper file</a></li><li>The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
<a href="apply.gradle.plugin">Apply Gradle plugin</a></li>